# Programmatic Content on a Node - preferably a non-code solution

Tags: 6, nodes

Trying to generate content ONLY when certain user roles are selected (and these roles would stack up, so lets say user 1 had roles A and B, they would have content for both roles A and B - logical AND), but only on certain pages.

How would I go about creating this?

Basically I want the logic to flow as such:

```
display content[default];

if userrole == A {
display content[A];
}
if userrole == B {
display content[B];
}
```

I'd prefer not to write any code, because A) I want it easily modifiable for the client and B) Well, it isn't my site!

Plus, code issues tend to be messier than module issues in my experience.

I've heard Panels or Ctools might be able to do this, but I'm unfamiliar as to how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) can do this.

Basic steps are:

- Install/enable panels and dependent modules.
- Make a new panel page
- Add your content pieces to the page
- For the per role pieces, click the options (the gear), and add a new visibility rule.  User: role should be in the list.  Configure accordingly.

Once you start the process, the terms I am using will make sense.

Comment: And this will allow content from both user: role A and user: role B to be displayed at the same time?

Comment: I misunderstood what your needs where and edited to better reflect what you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this using the [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for different portions of your site. You can think of each context as representing a "section" of your site. For each context, you can choose the conditions that trigger this context to be active and choose different aspects of Drupal that should react to this active context.
>
> Think of conditions as a set of rules that are checked during page load to see what context is active. Any reactions that are associated with active contexts are then fired.

Comment: Hrm, it does not seem to give me an option to add content to existing content on a page - just a block, which is already accomplished under putting a block with a conditional user role.